# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

*I know this error message why its coming its due to not having Google API.*

I am working with an application having maps in it and need to test this Application in XXHDPI devices ,but as a matter of fact Android directly not provided yet the support for XXHDPi devices.

So as a work around I found the solution with a little effort that Sony has introduced its SDK to support its device "Xperia Z". So i downloaded it and start my emulator of XXHDPI its working fine now.

But now here comes the Issue Sony SDK is a different and Google API is different without Sony SDK xxhdpi Devices emulator can`t be run and with it Maps can't be loaded so does any one have such **ISSUE** if so then please share it.

The issue of XXHDPI not directly run using Android native API 
reference is [Android Emulator](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39535)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Genymotion emulator. It is based on VirtualBox and they provide many different images. I just checked and it provides a device image with 1080 resolution and Google APIs installed.

[Link to their website](http://www.genymotion.com/)